# Some mistakes in Persia's tag information

Tags: discussion, tagging

Persia's tag information:

"The land and people in southwestern Asia from the ancient Sassanian empire to the modern nation state of Iran, prior to 1935"

1. The land and people: Wrong! Because Persia is the synonym of Iran not people of Iran. they are Iranians or Persians not Persia.
2. In southwestern Asia: Not wrong but not accurate! It is better to add the middle east or replace it with.
3. From the ancient Sassanian empire: Not wrong but cannot use it to refer to the ancient Iran before Sassanian ages. So what about Achaemenids? What about Ashkanian? What about Medians? or Elamites? These all were before Sassanid empire. So how can an user find historical events which have happened before this period of time in the civilized Iran?

Suggestion: Please accept the changes which I have done about information of this tag as only a synonym of Iran. Users can find all accurate information about ancient Iran under the tag of Ancient-Iran information. If we suppose an user tries Persia and doesn't know anything about Iran (weird!), s/he can find by synonyms like Iran and if s/he wants to know about ancient Iran there is a tag for this reason and solves his/her problems.

To find if you do not edit the Persia tag you have to ignore which parts of ancient Iran:

http://www.britannica.com/media/full/2029

Comment: I'm not familiar with Ashkanian - can you elaborate which time period it was?

Comment: It is the whole matter behind ancient-Iran in brief: 1.Before history 2.Elamites 3.Medians 4.Achaemenids(First Persian empire)(550-330 BC) 5.Soluki 6.Ashkanid(250-224 BC) 7.Sassanid 8.Arab attacks and Islam.

Comment: Ah, thanks. I knew 1-4 and 7-9 from my school history. 5&6 are new.

Comment: So it is interesting that you are insisting in giving wrong information to the audiences about it! Why? Is it a part of a propaganda? ;)

Comment: An interesting comparison to find biggest numbers of results according to key words by Googling in the Internet: Persia and Iran, Persia and ancient-Iran & Persian and Iranian:http://www.googlefight.com/index.php?lang=en_GB&word1=Persia&word2=Iran , http://www.googlefight.com/index.php?lang=en_GB&word1=Persian&word2=Iranian , http://www.googlefight.com/index.php?lang=en_GB&word1=Persia&word2=ancient+Iran

Comment: Dear close voter: Would you please leave a comment to know what is wrong with this question?! I think history is not a good play ground for prejudice,political directions and lie! All my attempts in this question is to prove we need reality and accuracy in this site not prejudice and imaginary stories which come from Hollywood scenarios. I would be happy to convince me about your idea! :)

Answer (score -1):

I would argue that : No, No and Yes.

1. "The land and people":

   As far as the wording "people", I suspect someone just copy/pasted a Wikipedia or dictionary article. Grammatically it's incorrect to add "and people" when using the term "Persia", you are correct.

   **However, I would argue that the wording is perfectly fine and should stay.**

   Remember that the tag Wiki is not exactly there to only define a term, but to define which questions should be tagged with the tag.

   As such, I would think that questions about Persian people should be tagged with "Persia" - and therefore, [persia](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/persia) tag can include such wording, instead of creating useless and misleading separate "persian-people" tag.
2. "Middle East" is a concept that changed as a term a LOT over the years, which is why it's best not to use it. It's more of a layman political term than a geographical term anyway. **"Southwest Asia" is a correct geographical location for it so that should stay**.
3. "Sassanid+": Achaemenid empire is known as "First Persian Empire" (and was called Parsā), therefore **you are definitely correct that this should be changed to "From the ancient  Achaemenid Empire" instead**.

   I don't know enough about Median Empire to be sure whether it should be lumped into Persia, or have its own separate tag instead (never mind an even earlier Elam). That may be a good question to ask on the main site.

Comment: I agree especially with the 1st "no", as the tag should be for both land and people living there.

Comment: Sorry you are wrong in some cases which I try to make you clear about: I disagree about using Persia for questions about Persian people as it is a complete ambiguous word for this reason. Persian people is used as synonym of Iranian people not people who were living after Sassanid empire. So what about Achameanid empire which was before Sassanid empire and Persian people who were living in that period pf time. Have you ever taken a look at the map of Persia in Achamaneid empire? Sassanid ws not the first Persian empire byt Achamaneid was the first which was hundreds years before Sassanid

Comment: about using Persia as a land and people It is clear that this usage is wrong and you cannot find such a thing through Googling. Please correct it as soon as possible. I am sorry but this bold mistakes makes all historians disappointed of you! :)

Comment: Good suggestion! About asking about in the main page but disagree about making new tags. I think it can make confusion in minds of users as you can put all of these question in ancient-iran tag. I think it is better before any more argument, correct mistakes of Persia tag and its information.

Comment: user37324, tags have slightly different function than stating what's true what's not from Iranian point of view. Their role is to help users from around the world to find what they're looking for. For example, there's no point in providing different tags for Kingdom of Poland, Polish&Lithuanian Commonwealth, Principality of Warsaw, Second Polish Republic and few other similar names that were valid during different centuries, if they all refer to the same thing, even if the borders and status of them was completely different and different nations lived inside of their areas.

Comment: And there would be completely no point in excluding questions about citizens of those countries from being tagged this way. That wouldn't help anybody, rather would be quite annoying. Do you really think that tagging every question with two tags like "iran" and "iranians" is better way? Be honest.

Comment: @DarekWędrychowski I think you insist in a wrong idea without any logical reason. It is better before useless and off topic arguments try to prove I am wrong. I talked according to documents not stories and my school history teacher's talks. I have never said we need two tags as if you read my comment again with more attention you will find it that I disagree with DVK to have more tags but I said it is better to correct bold ridiculous mistakes about Persia tag and stop using it instead of ancient-iran if you want to have it. It doesn't refer to Persian people or even ancient-iran as I said.

Comment: We have to talk according to facts and valid historical documents not irrelevant metaphors and fallacies about history!

Comment: @user37324 - you seem to be mistaking the purpose of SE tag wikis. They are not there to present definition of dictionary terms. They are there to explain which questions should be tagged with this tag. This MAY sometimes match dictionary definition, but doesn't have to. If it makes sense to tag questions about Persian people with "persia" tag (like they are done with every other country/civilization here), then tag wiki should reflect that, even if the dictionary definitio of the word "Persia" only refers to the country itself.

Comment: @DVK I know what I am saying. I repeat it may you find it too: It doesn't make sense to a person who knows about history not only in claims but can prove it by facts. Is there same information about the other tags? Anyway using Persia tag by this information for questions about ancient-iran is false.

Comment: Look: "The United States of America is a nation-state stretching across North America between Canada and Mexico, plus Alaska in the continent's northwest, the mid-Pacific archipelago of Hawaii and several territories in the Pacific & Caribbean. Founded by European émigrés rebelling from British control in." It is the information about United states of America with two synonyms which are USA,US and America!

Comment: Why there is so many arguments about Persia and its wrong information but not about the other countries' names? Is there any tag to refer to American people?

Comment: @user37324 - As to "why" - because you raise the issue on meta. If you didn't ask, I doubt anyone would care (as evidenced by people not caring about the topic before you asked)

Comment: @user37324 - if you think some other tag is incorrect, you can raise the point (especially by quoting both tags side by side) in a separate meta question. I only bothered lookint at this one because you raised it, I didn't bother looking at others because nobody raised questions about them.

Comment: Good suggestion! but information about USA tag is not wrong but about Persia is wrong! I only compared them to say if in a place a wrong is right so you have use it for some others too if not it seems ... .

Comment: @DVK Sorry, I will try to explain it easier maybe it is because of language barrier as I am not a native English speaker. I raised it because I care! If there is a right rule about tags it has to be used for all tags not only one tag. You pointed to a very interesting matter! So it is your reason (because I proved it is wrong here!) to insist in giving wrong information or careless writings to audiences in a forum about history which you claim you are trying to attract more people here and give them right information as experts. By this you will miss new audiences' trust.